# Improvement for a wood desk

Tags: wood, furniture, wooden-furniture, desk

Hello I want to attach this metal mesh grid panel to a wood desk which has a shelf on top, I plan to hang things like keychains and cables on it. The mesh did not come with anything used to attach it when I bought it, so now im wondering how to do it, preferably for cheap.

I have most basic tools and some random materials like sculpting wire and some epoxy but idk if those will hold with time.

[image: Metal mesh grid panel laying next to a piece of wood close up]

[image: Metal mesh grid panel laying next to a piece of wood fullview]

Comment: Zip ties or constrictor knots if you're trying to avoid puncturing the desk material.

Comment: If you're OK puncturing the desk material, some simple clamps would be fine, like these: https://www.homedepot.com/p/Gardner-Bender-1-4-in-Coaxial-Cable-Clamp-RG-6-20-Pack-PEC-31525WA/205588202

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you aren't putting much weight on it, I think I'd try wire guides of the sort that wrap around the wire and are then secured to the having material with a screw. How many you'd want would depend on the planned load. This would look a bit more official/permanent than zip ties. These are sometimes available in dark colors, if you can find those they'd make the anchoring points less obvious.

But this is the sort of project where it's often simplest to go into a hardware store, see what they have in the way of mounting hardware, and pick out something you think will work and not look bad. You're unlikely to go very far wrong; at worst you might miss a more elegant solution but almost anything that can grip both grid and uprights should work.

Heck, you could just drive an angled nail on each side and hang it from them, poor-man's-picture-hook style.

Comment: Or drive the nail straight and then knock it over, half-staple style.